# How to generate a sequence of Observables from an Observable that emits an array

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I have an array of Observable, for simplicity I generate a sample array below

```javascript
 dataList = of([Array(20).fill(0).map((_r,k) => k)]); // of([1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 20])
```

The above generates an `Observable` that emits an array. In the actual code this data is retrieved using an http call

Now what I am trying to achieve is this;

1. For each of this list generate a new `Observable` that emits each item after the Other

This I achieve using `flatMap` operator like below

```typescript
  flatMap(item => item )
```

2. Make an http request. For this I achieve using

```typescript
  mergeMap(i => this.myService.save(i))
```

3. Ensure that each request only starts after the last request

> this is where I have a problem

From [this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gifdbf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts), I have mocked an `http` request to return after 1 sec. From the console, all this are returned after 1 sec. But I would like this to be Something like

> http/1 
> http/2  (Delayed until `http/1` completes)
> http/3  (Delayed until `http/2` completes)
> http/4  (Delayed until `http/3` completes)
> ... 
> http/20  (Delayed until `http/19` completes)

Comment: Use `concatMap` instead of `mergeMap`. You can also use `from` instead of `of()` in this case and gete rid of `flatMap(item => item)`

Comment: @martin `concatMap` worked! For changing `of` to `from` may not be what I am looking for but changing  `mergeMap` to `concatMap` did exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably what you're after:

```
of(Array(20).keys()).pipe(
  mergeMap(list => list),
  concatMap(i => this.myService.save(i))
)
```

The following is another way to do the same thing, though it might make an idiomatic problem a bit more clear to see:

```
of(Array(20).keys()).pipe(
  mergeMap(list => list.map(
    i => this.myService.save(i)
  )),
  concatAll()
)
```

`concatMap` and `concatAll` store the buffering (backpressure) requests in an array, so it's a bit strange to turn an array into a stream and then immediately turn that stream back into an array.

The following approach skips that step by keeping your array whole and using the static `concat` operator (which takes an array of observables instead of a stream).

```
of(Array(20).keys()).pipe(
  map(list => list.map(
    i => this.myService.save(i))
  ),
  switchMap(httpList => concat(...httpList))
)
```

which can be combined into a single operator like this:

```
of(Array(20).keys()).pipe(
  switchMap(list => 
    concat(...list.map(
      i => this.myService.save(i)
    ))
  ),
)
```